Terraform set data source of key vault based on variable
I'm trying to set a data lookup for a username and password from a Key Vault to a SQL server via Terraform. I've got 3 environments Dev, UAT and Prod and have different creds for each environment. There is a variable for each environment of var.environment which is set in an environment .tfvars file. I've got secrets that've been added to a Key Vault already and are accessed via data sources.
I thought about using If OR but I can only set 2 values via this.
I've also looked at using locals with a tomap using something like
locals{
  username = tomap({
    devusername = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.username.value
    devpassword = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.password.value
  })
}

administrator_login = local.username[var.environment]

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "dev-username" {
  name         = "sql-username"
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.kv.id
}

And the environment variable is set at the tfvars level (there's one per env)
variable "environment" {
  type = string
}

However it doesn't look like you can put a data value into a map, just wondering if there's other ways of being able to set the username/password per environment.

There is no need to explicitly cast the local variable to a map. The question here is how are you defining the data source and how are you defining the environment variable, so adding that to the question would be helpful.

So the data source will always stay the same? I.e, the name argument will not change?


Set data source of key vault based on variable while using terraform

Thanks Marko E on this input. You don't need pass the name to map as mentioned just because you have different environments. In-order to pass the inputs for usernames and secrets while having multiple environment.
I tried a configuration which may not require to define the locals configuration again as per the requirement. before creating the secrets follow a naming convention that include the env name ex: dev-sql-password & dev-sql-username
this will while achieving the configuration mentioned below
demo configuration:
variable "environment" {
  type    = string
  default = "dev" 
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "sql_username" {
  name         = "${var.environment}-sql-username"
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.example.id
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "sql_password" {
  name         = "${var.environment}-sql-password"
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.example.id
}

locals {
  sql_username = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.sql_username.value
  sql_password = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.sql_password.value
}

resource "azurerm_mssql_server" "example" {
  name                         = "vksbbsqlserver-${var.environment}"
  resource_group_name          = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                     = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  version                      = "12.0"
  administrator_login          = local.sql_username
  administrator_login_password = local.sql_password
  minimum_tls_version          = "1.2"
}


deployment:


refer:
azurerm_mssql_server | Resources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform | Terraform Registry
